# Help choosing motor for a fruit cutting machine

Tags: motor, dc-motor, robotics, drill

I want assistance in determining an electric motor type suited to building a device for palm oil harvesting. Here is an example of one working [palm cutting machine.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nitzzuXfg8)

This machine works similar to a hammer drill machine or like a jackhammer but with lower torque. The application would require higher torque, but also should have good RPM to produce faster back and forth movement, producing short bursts of torque. I cannot decide what type of motor would be suitable for these type of applications. The motor should use DC power supply and be light weight.

I am not looking specific product recommendations, but just want to know which type of motors would best suit this application: DC, Universal, BLDC or something else?

Comment: Even if you would provide more details, this question will still be off topic since it's about product recommendations.

Comment: You need to define your requirements better. What working RPM and torque do you need? "Good RPM" is not a quantifiable metric.

Comment: I want to clarify that I am not looking for product recommendations, but just want to know which type of motors would these machines use, DC, Universal, BLDC or something else, for it to produce the bursts of torque

Comment: Bldc is efficient. Brushed dc is cheap, and universal can be treated as a subset of it.  Steppers are inefficient and limited in speed but give an inherent blind position control.  You'd do pretty well with the universal motors like in power tools; mind that you will probably need a gearbox.

Comment: This kind of tool will work best with a heavy spinning mass / flywheel used to drive the tool through load peaks. To allow it to slow down and provide that energy, you need a motor with a steep speed/torque curve like a series wound DC motor. Either that, or a current-driven motor to actively limit its output torque.

Comment: Your video is from the "chisel" sub-segment of [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vt5Wlz6Hr4Y&t=2m7s), which is more informative because it shows your desired "chisel", or "jackhammer", attachment in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are it's quite similar to Sawzall and similar devices.

So either a permanent magnet brushed DC motor and PWM speed control or a 3-phase BLDC motor and VFD controller and one or more powder metallurgy [planetary gear](https://www.machinedesign.com/mechanical-motion-systems/article/21834331/planetary-gears-the-basics) or bevel/helical gear reducers feeding a crank to get the reciprocating motion.

Both kinds of motor would best be turning in the high hundreds or low thousands of RPM to get full power, so you would need gear reduction to get slow enough speed and enough torque in a compact housing.

If you can put up with profuse profanity, innuendo and an exaggerated Canadian accent, a youtuber called [AvE](https://youtu.be/UXBiBK0TYew?si=DIkyqzHo_n860x43) does some quite knowledgeable teardowns of such tools (like this skookum Milwaukee).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, video was very helpful. I think it is a brushed DC motor, I found the model: https://www.ebay.com/itm/255200827697

Answer (score 3):

There is much in the internet on the characteristics of such machines.
You can use existing examples to determine the power and shaft speeds that are required. This will make motor specification easier.

From what I've seen at a quick skim a brushless DC motor designed for low RPM operation "(low "kv") - so many poles - and probably hundreds of Watts power - the more the better. The examples below provide an idea of motor to mechanism coupling.

Here is a design paper that looks useful. It's written in 'Indonesian'. I tried Google translate with mixed results. This (apparently) uses an internal combustion motor but shows what is involved in design.

Introduction page [here](https://jurnalkelapasawit.iopri.org/index.php/jpks/article/view/183)

Paper
[The Design of a Motorized Palm Portable Harvesting Tool using a Flexible Shaft - Indonesian language version](https://jurnalkelapasawit.iopri.org/index.php/jpks/article/view/183/126)

Here is another paper of possible use. This also uses an internal combustion motor but shows what is involved in design.

[DEVELOPMENT AND EVALUATION OF A NEW GENERATION OIL PALM MOTORISED CUTTER](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324769041_DEVELOPMENT_AND_EVALUATION_OF_A_NEW_GENERATION_OIL_PALM_MOTORISED_CUTTER_Cantas_Evo#pf4)

Full paper can be read using "Read full text" button, or downloaded via Research Gate.